# Overlap of group of scripts

Tags: oracle, scripting

I have a group of scripts set to run in a certain order, but sometimes I find the group running long and overlapping into the next group run.   Is there a way to prevent that?

group.sh:
script1.sh &
wait
script2.sh &
wait
script3.sh

group.sh is still running (perhaps on script3.sh) when group.sh kicks off for the next run.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a Unix question, and you're not using OEM Cloud Control etc. I tend to do this by using a temporary file (with a known name) that indicates whether the script is still running or not. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /tmp/groupisrunning ] ; then  
  # do not execute if the process is already running. This is controlled by the 
  # the existence of the above file

  echo "Already running" 

else

  touch /tmp/groupisrunning

   # DO YOUR WORK BELOW THIS LINE, eg: 
  script1.sh
  script2.sh
  script3.sh
  rm -f /tmp/groupisrunning
fi
```

There are other ways of doing this (`ps` parsing, using a service), but I find this simple & reliable.

Comment: I have seen that used for backups by a vendor and it came back to bite us.  The server crashed during the seasonal time change when a backup was running.  When it was rebooted all the following attempts to backup the server stopped as the temp file was still there.

Comment: 100% in agreement

Comment: @kevinsky - well, no solution is perfect, and that's the most elegant solution that I've ever seen +1. It's not too much of a stretch to assume that sysadmins will have **documented** procedures and checks to run in the event of a crash which can easily check for the existence of such "signal" files.

Comment: @Vérace Yes, you would assume that a database support vendor that offers services around the world 24 hours a day would have documented procedures to cover off a server crash.  Management was unpleasantly surprised that in addition to backups not taking place there was also no provision to alert on no backups....

Comment: Care to hint as to who this vendor migth be?

Comment: @kevinsky `/tmp` doesn't actually persist over reboots on modern Linux distros anyway, as they use tmpfs